# Pictures inside drawable layout fragment

Tags: android, eclipse

i am new in java and android so i tried to do simple application with drawable layout and fragments. I now know how to load websites in app but i don't know how to show some pictures inside drawable layout fragment. I hope you guys have any ideas how can i show some pictures in one fragment. Any help is appreciated.

This is my photos_fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Photos View"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtLabel"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photos"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my PhotosFragment.java:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment {

    public PhotosFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem ur code will load `ic_photos` when fragmet will attach with `Activity`

Comment: The question is, HOW do you want to add SOME picture in fragment?

in single imageview multiple picture or multiple imageviews with different pictures.

Comment: I want to add in single imageview multiple pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do google.It is so simple that you will get it from very first example.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false);

ImageView image = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
return rootView;
```

image is the id of ImageView

Comment: But i want to add multiple pictures inside fragment. I aleready tried to google it but i couldnt get the answer. I know how to show only one picture but i don't know how to show multiple pictures inside fragment.

Comment: I figured out how can i make it. I just made simple HTML code wehere i add pictures and then my webview load it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int imageresource = getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/pizza", "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());

image.setImageResource(imageresource);
```